# How to show the average score?

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving the scores of a game with PHP and MySQL, the table looks like this.

```
ID USERID SCORE
1  23     200
2  45     145
3  64     231
```

etc...

Now what PHP or MySQL code can let me show the average scores ?
Thanks.

Comment: refer this : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx
and
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlavg.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user's average score?  This should do it:

```
SELECT USERID, AVG(SCORE) AS AVERAGE_SCORE
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY
    USERID
```

For the entire table:

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE) AS AVERAGE_SCORE
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: No the average scores of all users, all the table

Comment: simply remove the group by statement then,... and learn sql^^

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(`SCORE`) as AVG_SCORE FROM `YOURTABLE`
```

Answer (score 0):

For entire table

```
SELECT AVG(score) AS average_score FROM 'table'
```

Comment: there is an avg() function which is probably more efficient than this.

Comment: @mightyuhu: exactly, not remembered before!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE) FROM SCORES
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE) FROM TableName
```